# ASP.NET 4.5: Attribute 'modeltype' is not a valid attribute of element 'FormView'

Tags: asp.net, model-binding

I am building an ASP.NET Web Form in VS 11 & want to use **Model Binding** feature of ASP.NET 4.5. The problem is that the **ModelType** attribute of **FormView** tag is not shown in the Intellisense list. If I try to type it manually in the source, I will get the following message:

**Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'modeltype' is not a valid attribute of element 'FormView'**

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved

The problem was that **ModelType** attribute (new in ASP.NET 4.5) - which is introduced in contributors' blogs across the Internet so many several times - has been renamed to **ItemType** without any notice. One can find it in *Properties Palette* of Data Controls in VS 11.

*I wonder why it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentations and blogs.*

Cheers